# Hibernate mapping exception: unknown entity

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am new to Java and just started learning Hibernate from an online tutorial. I have created java code with Hibernate but after that i have been failing to test run.
I have database table "users" in MySQL  Database "test". when i try to insert a record it gives me this error. Cant find the exact reason..

Stack:

```
    710 [main] INFO org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory - Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: in.shivasoft.pojo.Users
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:580)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1365)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:562)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:550)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:546)
    at in.shivasoft.test.TestMain.saveRecord(TestMain.java:33)
    at in.shivasoft.test.TestMain.main(TestMain.java:19)
```

---

```
   my Users.hbm.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd" >
    <hibernate-mapping>
    <class entity-name="Users" name="in.shivasoft.pojo.Users" table="Users">
    <meta attribute="description">This class is used to save the info about users</meta>
    <id column="UserId" name="UserId" type="long"/>
    <property column="FName" name="FName" type="string"/>
    <property column="LName" name="LName" type="string"/>
    <property column="UserTypeId" name="UserTypeId" type="long"/>
    <property column="UserName" name="UserName" type="string"/>
    <property column="Email" name="Email" type="string"/>
    <property column="Pwd" name="Pwd" type="string"/>
    <property column="Note" name="Note" type="string"/>
    <property column="IsActive" name="IsActive" type="boolean"/>
    </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

---

Hibernate Configuration(hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">1234</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/test</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property**strong text**>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
  <mapping resource="in/shivasoft/pojo/Users.hbm.xml"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

---

This is Entity class created by Hibernate code Generation

```
package in.shivasoft.pojo;

// Generated Sep 27, 2013 11:48:09 AM by Hibernate Tools 4.0.0

/**
 * Users generated by hbm2java
 */
public class Users implements java.io.Serializable {

    private long UserId;
    private String FName;
    private String LName;
    private long UserTypeId;
    private String UserName;
    private String Email;
    private String Pwd;
    private String Note;
    private boolean IsActive;

    public Users() {
    }

    public Users(long UserId) {
        this.UserId = UserId;
    }

    public Users(long UserId, String FName, String LName, long UserTypeId,
            String UserName, String Email, String Pwd, String Note,
            boolean IsActive) {
        this.UserId = UserId;
        this.FName = FName;
        this.LName = LName;
        this.UserTypeId = UserTypeId;
        this.UserName = UserName;
        this.Email = Email;
        this.Pwd = Pwd;
        this.Note = Note;
        this.IsActive = IsActive;
    }

    public long getUserId() {
        return this.UserId;
    }

    public void setUserId(long UserId) {
        this.UserId = UserId;
    }

    public String getFName() {
        return this.FName;
    }

    public void setFName(String FName) {
        this.FName = FName;
    }

    public String getLName() {
        return this.LName;
    }

    public void setLName(String LName) {
        this.LName = LName;
    }

    public long getUserTypeId() {
        return this.UserTypeId;
    }

    public void setUserTypeId(long UserTypeId) {
        this.UserTypeId = UserTypeId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return this.UserName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String UserName) {
        this.UserName = UserName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.Email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String Email) {
        this.Email = Email;
    }

    public String getPwd() {
        return this.Pwd;
    }

    public void setPwd(String Pwd) {
        this.Pwd = Pwd;
    }

    public String getNote() {
        return this.Note;
    }

    public void setNote(String Note) {
        this.Note = Note;
    }

    public boolean isIsActive() {
        return this.IsActive;
    }

    public void setIsActive(boolean IsActive) {
        this.IsActive = IsActive;
    }

}
```

This is my TestMain.Java

```
package in.shivasoft.test;


import in.shivasoft.pojo.Users;
import in.shivasoft.util.HibernateUtil;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

public class TestMain {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestMain obj = new TestMain();
        obj.saveRecord();
        obj.getList();
    }

    public void saveRecord()
    {
        Users u = new Users(0, "Jitendra", "Zaa", 1, "jitendra.zaa", "jitendra.zaa@shivasoft.in", "test", "this is note", true);
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try
        {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(u);
            transaction.commit();
            System.out.println("Data Saved");
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{session.close();}

    }

    public void updateUser(long UserId)
    {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try
        {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            Users u = (Users)session.get(Users.class,UserId);
            u.setFName("ShivaSoft");
            transaction.commit();
            System.out.println("Data Updated");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            session.close();
        }
    }

    public void getList()
    {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try
        {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            List<Users> uList = List<Users> uList = Session.createCriteria(Users.class).list();
            for(Users u : uList)
            {
                System.out.println("First Name - "+u.getFName());
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

---

This is log for session Factory Dont know if there is problem with it..

```
10 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.3.1.GA
13 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false}
15 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
19 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
61 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
61 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
128 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Reading mappings from resource : in/shivasoft/pojo/Users.hbm.xml
197 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder - Mapping class: Users -> users
208 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configured SessionFactory: null
256 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
256 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - Hibernate connection pool size: 20
256 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - autocommit mode: false
262 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - using driver: org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver at URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
262 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
499 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - RDBMS: MySQL, version: 5.6.14-log
499 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JDBC driver: MySQL-AB JDBC Driver, version: mysql-connector-java-5.1.0 ( $Date: 2007-04-05 23:56:05 +0200 (Thu, 05 Apr 2007) $, $Revision: 6376 $ )
515 [main] INFO org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
518 [main] INFO org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionFactoryFactory - Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
519 [main] INFO org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookupFactory - No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)
519 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
519 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
520 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JDBC batch size: 15
520 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JDBC batch updates for versioned data: disabled
520 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Scrollable result sets: enabled
520 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): enabled
520 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Connection release mode: auto
521 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Maximum outer join fetch depth: 2
521 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Default batch fetch size: 1
521 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Generate SQL with comments: disabled
521 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled
521 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled
521 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
523 [main] INFO org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory - Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
523 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query language substitutions: {}
523 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JPA-QL strict compliance: disabled
523 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Second-level cache: enabled
523 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query cache: disabled
523 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.impl.NoCachingRegionFactory
523 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled
523 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
527 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Statistics: disabled
528 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
528 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Default entity-mode: pojo
528 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Named query checking : enabled
568 [main] INFO org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl - building session factory
737 [main] INFO org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory - Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
```

Comment: Is your package declaration correct, need TestMain.java snippet as well to check!

Comment: What happening if you try to select records? Try before saving `session.getCriteria(Users.class).list();`

Comment: try `session.persist(u);` instead of save.

Comment: still getting same error with  `session.persist(u);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove 'entity-name' attribute in user.hbm.xml. it will work fine. 
DO like this "class name="in.shivasoft.pojo.Users" table="Users"

[here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/xml.html) and [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-class) you wil get to know why you need to remove that 'entity-name' attribute name

Comment: i have pasted my entity class also above in this question but i created it with the hibernate code generation please see if there is something wrong with it..

Comment: remove 'entity-name' attribute in user.hbm.xml. it will work fine. DO like this     <class name="in.shivasoft.pojo.Users" table="Users">

Comment: [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/xml.html)   you wil get to know why you need to remove that 'entity-name' attribute name

Comment: ohhhh Finally... sigh !

Comment: what about annotation. i am getting same error in annotation.